# Automatically input defined password when shell prompts?

Tags: go

I am writing a Golang application which will run some bash scripts. In one of the commands the script will run as sudo and it would require me to enter a password manually.

May I know how to achieve sending of password automatically?

```
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "knife bootstrap xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -x user_name --sudo -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub --node-name node_name -P password -c ~/chef-repo/.chef/config.rb")

stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}

go func() {
    defer stdin.Close()
    io.WriteString(stdin, "password")
}()
```

I am currently stuck at the step when knife bootstrap will prompt the following for a password over at the chef client side.

```
user_name@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
```

I couldn't use expect to capture this string and provide the password, it seems to be different from the usual strings that will output in the terminal.

Comment: @Flimzy I updated the question to include the portion of my code. If you run this in Golang it will still prompt for password and not automatically return the password when prompt due to it being an input in a terminal. Anyway to resolve this?

Comment: You can either use `cmd.StdinPipe`, or use a proper [ssh package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh).

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I am currently having an issue expecting a prompt from knife bootstrap command. Do you happen to use it before?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need use `sudo -S`.

> echo password | sudo -S vim a.txt

Comment: In my case, I am testing out with the ssh command. Anyway to echo the password for input terminal (which the prompt is at)?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I found a package that helps to handle Expect inside Golang. You can take a look at https://github.com/google/goexpect if you are interested.